# Can't load Visual Studio project due to missing Microsoft.PythonTools.Django.Targets file

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, web-development-server

I've cloned my project from a GitHub repository and have been receiving the following error upon opening the project in Visual Studio:

`C:\path\to\project\test.pyproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Python Tools\Microsoft.PythonTools.Django.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Python Tools\Microsoft.PythonTools.Django.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_e9ead341\devenv.exe.config". Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.  C:\path\to\project\test.pyproj`

I've tried changing the  declaration and have tried verifying that I have all of the proper Visual Studio workloads installed, but the problem persists. The project is a web application running Python using Django on the back end and JavaScript on the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue can happen if there is something wrong with the  declaration or if a necessary Visual Studio component is missing. In this case there was simply a missing component. More specifically, while the Python development workload was installed, the optional "Python web support" component was not. To install this, open up the Visual Studio Installer, select "Modify," open the "Individual components" tab, and search for "Python Web Support" and begin the install. It should be noted that this can also be installed as an optional component of the "Python development" from the "Workloads" tab.